# Cleverbot auto reply

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Which technology is used by cleverbot to give auto reply. As I want to research on it and later on built on cleverbot like web application of my own native language. I am in initial stage exploring how it can be made, your answer will be valuable to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleverbot

Answer (score 1):

https://cmdbot.readthedocs.org/en/1.0.3/your_bot.html :) try reading this page! It explains how it works.

Comment: I cannot seem to find anything...probably it can, but you need to think it all :) This one is made in python....(the one from the cmdbot link :) ...here is the link to the source code https://github.com/brunobord/cmdbot

Comment: No problem! If it helped you, make sure to select the answer, this way you help others with the same problem!